# How to declare that an object satisfies a Record with function values that accept any number of arguments in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How do I declare an object that allows typescript to infer the strictest type but also constrain it's values to be function that return a string for any number of function parameters.

For example

```
const stringFactory = {
  a: (): string => '',
  b: (input: Array<string>): string => input.join(' '), // error
} satisfies { [K: string]: (...params: Array<unknown>) => string };
```

However, this results in the error

```
Type '(input: Array<string>) => string' is not assignable to type '(...params: unknown[]) => string'.   Types of parameters 'input' and 'params' are incompatible.     Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.ts(2322)
```

I tried also (i) annotating the object `stringFactory` with the type `{ [K: string]: (...params: Array<unknown>) => string }`. This results in the same error

(ii) using variation of a Record or an interface

```
const stringFactory = {
  a: (): string => '',
  b: (input: Array<string>): string => input.join(' '), // error
} satisfies Record<string, (...params: Array<unknown>) => string }>;
```

(iii) Substituting unknown with never, this works but seems like a less than ideal workaround

```
const stringFactory = {
  a: (): string => '',
  b: (input: Array<string>): string => input.join(' '), // error
} satisfies Record<string, (...params: Array<never>) => string }>;
```

(iv) I would prefer not to use `any`

Comment: in this scenario, it really doesn't matter if you use `any` instead of `unknown`. So changing `Array<unknown>` to `Array<any>` would be the easiest solution

Comment: Hmm, `never` is correct here, since functions are contravariant in their parameters; why does it "seem like a less than ideal workaround"?  (Actually `(...args: never) => string` is the right type and not `Array<never>`, which technically should require 0 params, but I think the compiler special-cases it). What [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3ELEw) do you consider "less than ideal"?  I'd love to post an answer to this question but I'm worried that you've got good reason for rejecting `never` here.  How should I proceed?

Comment: @jcalz thanks I guess I haven't fully wrapped my head around why `...args: Array<unknown>` does not work in this case. Since it seems it should be the correct type. The values in the object should satisfy `(...params: Array<unknown>) => string` in that the parameters are a varying list of arguments that the `satisfies` constraint does not need to care about...

Comment: If `X extends Y` then `((a: Y)=>void) extends ((a: X)=>void)` and not vice versa.  If I want an animal and you give me a cat, that's fine.  But if I'm looking to hire a veterinarian (`(a: Animal) => void`) but you're some sort of cat-specific doctor (`(a: Cat) => void`) then you're not hired, sorry. You can say "well a cat is an animal" but that's not relevant.  A `(...a: unknown[])=>void` must accept any arguments the caller wants to pass, and `(x: string[])=>void` isn't hired, sorry. Does that make sense? If so I'll write up my full answer explaining; if not, what remains confusing?

Comment: @jcalz I think that makes _some_ sense. Here's how I would paraphrase it in my own words as an attempt to grok it

If I want an animal then I will accept a cat

if I want something that takes any animal, I will not accept something that takes only cats

In this case I've expressed that I want a function that takes some `unknown` arguments, but I've supplied a function that takes a `string` of arguments. But it is not general enough to handle `unknown` arguments...

Is that a reasonable way to reason about it?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper supertype for all functions that return `string` is `(...params: never) => string`, using [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) not `(...args: unknown[]) => string`.

That's because functions are *contravariant* in their parameters, see [the TS release notes for `--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) for more information and links about contravariance.

The function `(input: Array<string>): string => input.join(' ')` is *not* an `(...params: unknown[]) => string` because the latter must accept any arguments the caller wants to send.  Such a function could be called like `f(2)` and then your implementation would try to use the nonexistent `join()` method of a `number`.  Oops.

On the other hand, it's a perfectly acceptable `(...params: never) => string`, since that type cannot be safely called at all... you'll never find an argument list of type `never` to pass it.  So you'll never run into a way of calling `(...params: never) => string` that would cause `(input: Array<string>): string => input.join(' ')` to explode.

So the proper way to write your code is

```
const stringFactory = {
  a: (): string => '', // okay
  b: (input: Array<string>): string => input.join(' '), // okay
} satisfies { [k: string]: (...params: never) => string };
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOBLMBzAYgQ2FE8CeMAvDAN4BQMMGAXDABQCUtCyKRAfDAORcA0MAegEwQAawx4KMAEa06yAA4BXKLQCC8eBIA8LVOyZwoSVBxiKVAOgBWIZHS7cG-ISPGSAvnAxREEAGaIAKYQpDAA2qLMxqwAunKWiQoYWgC2ELRgQQBuQfAMZnpsHgDcQA)

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail